# How to include variable in Regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, file-upload, jquery-file-upload

I want to use regex to allow/reject files during fileupload with a specific file type.

This is the working regex `/(\.|\/)(xlsx)$/i` expected output that I want to achieve.

What I'm trying is instead of hardcode the filetype, I want to pass a variable that holds filetype into the regex.

```
var fileType = 'xlsx';
var regexText = new RegExp("/(\.|\/)(" + fileType + ")$/i");
```

but the current output of regexText is `/\/(.|\/)(xlsx)$\/i/` this is not same as expected output. How do I can get same output as mentioned above by using a variable without hardcode? Is there solution without using the RegExp that can give the same expected output?

Comment: Look at the [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) constructor. You don't need the leading `/`, double escape the backslash and the `/i` flag should go as the second parameter. Note that you can write the alternation as a character class.

Answer (score 0):

try forming string for regex line before calling new RegExp